Domain Whitelisting AWS-based Appliciation in Hyperforce
Is there a way to whitelist a list of domains instead of IP Addresses in Salesforce after Hyperforce migration similar to allowlisting introduced here documentation but for incoming applications?
We have a bunch of AWS-based third party applications that use dynamic IP ranges and we're  struggling to maintain them in Salesforce via Login IP ranges. If you guys have an alternative, i would appreciate any recommendations.
Saw several posts that are similar but they  did not get any traction sadly :(. Hope anyone can help.
